# Declare non-void method as lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I really like how you can quickly implement interfaces using lambdas, the code becomes much shorter and more readable... We can use lambdas to implement properties

```
public ICollection<TKey> Keys => _dict.Keys;

public TValue this[TKey key] { get => _dict[key]; set => _dict[key] = value; }
```

...or even methods

```
public void Clear() => _dict.Clear();
```

But I can't figure out how to rewrite a non-void method using lamdbas? Like this one for example:

```
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
{
    return _dict.ContainsKey(key);
}
```

Comment: `public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => _dict.ContainsKey(key);` ?

Comment: Also, these aren't really lambda expressions, rather "expression bodied members".. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is the same:

```
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => _dict.ContainsKey(key);
```

Also, these aren't really lambda expressions, rather "expression bodied members"; see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator